# How to adjust width in Nogray timepicker input?

Tags: javascript, html, css, timepicker

```
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ng_all.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ng_ui.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/components/timepicker.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    ng.ready(function() {
      var my_timepicker = new ng.TimePicker({
        input: 'my_timepicker'
      });
    });
  </script>
  <style>
    #my_timepicker {
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  Time : <br><input id="my_timepicker" name="my_timepicker_input" style="width:10px" type="text" autocomplete="off" required><br><br>
</body>

</html>
```

This is my html to use Nogray time picker. I can't adjust the width of input. And i have tried to understand source code but it is too difficult for me. Can anyone say another way of doing it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of identifying element by id, i have used class attribute to set the width in css. Hence its working well!.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, nogray timepicker doesn't use the input given in the body. It will create a new input element above it and the input `my_timepicker` will be hidden. So when we get element by id, it actually points to the `my_timepicker` input. But when we add a class to `my_timepicker` input, it will add the same class to the nogray created input also. Therefore when we get element by class, it actually points to the nogray created input.

Answer (score 0):

Nogray timepicker use the input "my_timepicker" only for get the position where they want to create actuall inputs.
input show on the browser is not the input given by you.
You can observe it by clicking inspect element on the input.

However any class added to the user defined input will also added to nogray created input. That's why css worked when you select it by class and not when you select it by id.